# Yii - Case-sensitivity of the table name, column in sql query

Tags: yii

How to get rid of case-sensitive dependence in database query in Yii, using different ways to access the database, either through Active Record, DAO, and through the query designer.

Answer (score 1):

First of all to avoid case sensitive dependence in database query, you need to make the database case insensitive by setting a flag in configuration file as in MySQL, Which will make all database queries case insensitive

Comment: To set the mysql COLLATE = 'utf8_unicode_ci'
lower_case_table_names = 1
It does not help :-(

And more interested in Oracle

Comment: Where did you add this.